# Rails:NoMethodError in GetFields#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to create something by using new route path:

```
 new_project_interface_get_field GET /projects/:project_id/interfaces/:interface_id/get_fields/new(.:format)      get_fields#new
```

I have tried many ways but it does not seem correct and it shows

> undefined method `id' for `nil:NilClass`

```
<%=link_to  new_project_interface_get_field_path(@project.id,@interface.id) do %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"></button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Either `@project` or `@interface` is `nil`.

Comment: I also tried  new_project_interface_get_field_path(@project,@interface)，but it still not correct.

Comment: Of course, it’s incorrect. It requires `id`s. The issue is **as I already said** one (or both) instance variables are `nil` (not initialized in the controller.)

Comment: Still, either `@project` or `@interface` is `nil`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I will go to check. thx you

Comment: @MarekLipka I have found problems. I have not find id inside the def index. it should be                                                                                                                  
 def index
    project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    interface = Interface.find(params[:interface_id])
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the variables you are passing in are nil.

Have you tried checking what's actually being passed into your parameters for the params[:project_id] and params[:interface_id]? If those return an ID, maybe there are no actual Projects/Interface records in your database that match, in which case you'll need to revisit wherever you're passing in your params (or the database you're testing with).